# Drawing a loop in a "tree" using the forest package

Tags: forest

Is it possible to add a loop to a tree in the `forest` package? Specifically, how can I typeset the diagram on the right? (Ignore the colors, just usual black on white.)

[image]

The code for the left one (without the red `X`) is:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={grow=north}
[$\oplus$
    [$\otimes$
        []
        []
    ]
    [$\otimes$
        []
        []
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please post complete code people can compile? It makes it much easier to help - no need to guess how to complete examples - and more likely it *will* help - no danger of completing in an incompatible way.

Comment: The problem is that the diagram on the right is not a tree. In a tree, a child has one parent - never two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagram on the right is not a tree since a child has more than one parent. Hence, it cannot be drawn in Forest out-of-the-box. However, you can have Forest draw the loop by manipulating `edge path`, using `tikz` or adding Ti*k*Z commands directly inside the `forest` environment.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    grow=north,
  },
  where n children=0{tier=terminus}{},
  [$\oplus$
      [$\otimes$
          []
          [, phantom]
      ]
      [, edge path'={(!r1.parent anchor) -- (.child anchor) (!rl.parent anchor) -- (.child anchor)}, child anchor=south]
      [$\otimes$
          [, phantom]
          []
      ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: non-tree hack]

If you only need the odd non-tree bit, this should be fine. If, however, you need many loops, you will want to use support for generic graphs, avoiding the packages and libraries which focus on trees. Consider the Ti*k*Z graphs provision in that case.